# Может ли вводное слово выделяться с одной стороны запятой, а с другой стороны - тире?

Tags: вводные-слова

У Розенталя: (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100)

7. При наличии вводных слов, связывающих однородные члены предложения, после последнего из них запятая не ставится: В результате сила электромагнитного поля проходящих сигналов, а значит, и сила приёма увеличиваются во много раз. Странный, если хотите — вызывающий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих.

Почему вводные "если хотите" выделены запятой и тире, а не двумя запятыми или двумя тире?

Можно ли рассуждать так:

Странный, если хотите, вызывающий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих.

Здесь первая запятая одновременно служит для соединения однородных членов: странный, вызывающий, а также для выделения вводных слов "если хотите".

Странный, — если хотите — вызывающий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих.

Здесь запятая служит для соединения однородных членов: странный, вызывающий, а парное тире выделяет вводные слова "если хотите".

Answer (score 1):

Может так отделяться. Тире после вводного слова — интонационное.

Интонационное тире как бы заменяет слово "даже", усиливая прилагательное "вызывающий".

Тире перед словом "если" нельзя назвать естественным. Смотрится плохо. Два тире больше при вставных предложениях (которых нет в справочниках). В таких предложениях, как правило, есть и подлежащее, и сказуемое. А у нас больше вводное словосочетание.

Ещё пример Розенталя:
*Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того — восхищался им.* || Тире употребляется перед пафосным словом, чтобы интонация была соответствующей.

Такое тире часто употребляется перед важной или контрастной информацией, чтобы интонация была более активной. В данных примерах у нас контраст (тире можно заменить на слово "даже").

Answer (score 1):

Рассуждать можно так. Здесь возможны два варианта:

(1) *СтрАнный, **если хотите**, вызывАющий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих.
Он глубоко уважАл своего друга, **более того,** восхищАлся им.*

(2) *СтрАнный, **если хотИте** — вызывАющий тон неприятно подействовал на окружающих. Он глубоко уважАл своего друга, **бОлее того** — восхищАлся им.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118 
В роли уточняющего может выступать сочетание слов ***более того***: Было бы глупостью, более того, безумием упустить такой случай; Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того — восхищался им.

**И усиливается** здесь при обособлении тире **не "пафосное" слово** (прилагательное или глагол), а вводное или уточняющее слово. Потому что в этом случае на него падает **дополнительное** ударение.

Можно ли такое тире называть **интонационным**? Если только в очень условном смысле, так как тире здесь используется для обособления вводного или уточняющего слова  вместо второй запятой, то есть по **грамматическим** показателям.

Comment: А без пафосного слова вы бы тоже тире поставили? *Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того, часто ходил к нему в гости. Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того, много времени с ним проводил.* Пафосность и ваше ударение взаимосвязаны. Причина замены запятой на тире не грамматическая, а интонационная. Ясное дело, что грамматическую функцию тире выполняет тоже.

Comment: Дорогой друг! Жаль, конечно, всё время вас огорчать, но вы, как всегда, неправы. Неправы, когда придумываете предложения, которые не отражают реальную коммуникативную ситуацию, да еще делаете из них какие-то выводы. Неправы и по поводу интонационного тире. Пожалуйста, загляните в справочник Розенталя, у него это вполне определенный термин http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94  А вы, вероятно, говорите об интонационном тире в общекультурном смысле.  В том смысле что тире, как и всякий другой знак, выражает определенную интонационно-грамматическую структуру предложения.

Comment: Неправы вы. Почему? Интонационное тире - это факультативное тире. Или, по-вашему, его обязательно ставить в данных примерах? Тогда на основе какого правила?

Comment: На основе правила обособления вводных слов. По Розенталю, они обособляются запятыми, но также возможно использование тире. Варианты семантически различаются, при использовании тире подчеркивается вводное (но уж никак не ваше пафосное слово). А интонационного тире не имеет грамматического обоснования, там выбор делается только по интонации.

Comment: Как жаль, что вы верите учёным, но не понимаете суть. Вводное слово подчёркивается, но это обусловлено контекстом (окружающими словами). Будь вокруг другие слова - тире бы могли не поставить. А тире ставится перед тем, что будет дальше, а не после чего-то, что нужно подчеркнуть. Мы не читаем справа налево.

Comment: Да понимаете, книги-то всё учёные люди пишут,  вот и приходится с ними общаться. А сами знаете, с кем поведешься...  Но вот вы, к примеру... Вы о сути вещей рассуждаете, а с логикой у вас как? Почитайте, что вы мне написали. "Вводное слово подчеркивается... а тире ставится перед тем, что надо подчеркнуть (в нашем случае перед "пафосным" словом". То есть подчеркнуто совсем не то, что надо подчеркнуть?

Comment: Единственное, что вас может извинить, так это то, что это всеобщее заблуждение (насчет подчеркивания). Как видите, я всё-таки учёным не всегда верю. Опять же, как говорится, доверяй, но проверяй. Хотите немного "просветлиться"? Тогда скажите, что подчеркнуто в цитате из Паустовского,  подлежащее или сказуемое? "Писательство – не ремесло и не занятие. Писательство – призвание".

Comment: Нет, вы не понимаете. Суть такова. Ударение (условно подчёркивание) падает на вводное слово за счёт увеличенной паузы от тире. Вследствие этого заметно уменьшается оттенок вводности. А тире ставится перед важной информацией или контрастной, перед переломными моментами, как говорит Розенталь. И произносится это с более яркой интонацией. Тире не указывает на то, что нужно вернуться назад и ещё раз прочитать вводное слово как-то иначе. Если бы нужно было подчеркнуть конкретно вводное слово, то тире бы поставили перед ним, а не после. Мы же не читаем справа налево. В цитате можно подставить "это".

Comment: Ладно, разбирайтесь сами с уменьшением "оттенка вводности"  и "яркой интонацией" - я   такими категориями при анализе в принципе не мыслю (это как нибудь без меня).  Также любопытно мне показалось, что вы читателю предлагаете возвращаться от конца предложения к его началу (для постижения смысла), в то время как наши современники  книги предпочитают читать по диагонали. Поэтому ввиду взаимного непонимания сути вещей -  bye-bye.

Comment: А вы хитры. В цитате тире ставится на основе совсем другого правила. Там речь не идёт о усилении запятой тире. Во втором предложении тире вообще обязательно. Рассчитывали, что я на этом проколюсь и скажу, что подчёркивается сказуемое. Но не тут-то было. Уменьшение оттенка вводности: вводные слова произносятся быстрее, чем обычные, а за счёт тире произношение медленнее (похоже на обычные слова). А что значит "читать по диагонали"? Я чуть догадываюсь, но слабовато. В школе же этому не учат.

Comment: Школьник, а интернет-то  у вас есть? Тогда вам - туда. В наше время такие информационные возможности, что каждый  еще в школе может стать академиком.

Comment: Просто имел в виду, что раз в школе это не изучают, то большинство людей не знает об этом. Просто хотелось услышать от вас. Как-то думал, что это просто быстро читать, не проговаривая слова. И в интернете то же самое. То есть это не о том, что читать наперёд.

Comment: И что мне в сами делать? Можно же было найти, например, это:https://magicspeedreading.com/k/key_chtenie_po_diagonali.html

Comment: У меня как раз открыт этот сайт. Там нет о том, чтобы читать наперёд. В этом смысла нет. Всё равно читается подряд. Наперёд читают только музыканты. Да и читать не проговаривая могут лишь избранные. Книги на них точно не ориентированы.

Comment: Ладно, забудем про диагональ.  "Мы же не читаем справа налево". Ваши слова? А про анафорические местоимения слышали? Это он, она, то, те. Вот эти слова указывают на предшествующее слово, отсылают нас  к ранее сказанному, то есть слева направо. Вот и подумайте  на досуге, каким знаком является тире и куда оно нас отсылает, вперед или назад. В заданном предложении однородные прилагательные в любом случае находятся под ударением. А тире относится к предшествующему вводному слову и предлагает выделить ударением и его тоже.  Не согласны? Тогда это ваши трудности. Еще раз bye-bye.

Comment: Местоимения ссылаются на то, что было раньше, так как читающий уже знает, на что именно. А мы увидели тире - и должны повторно прочитать, чтобы выделить? Ударение не означает обязательное подчёркивание. Такое слово вполне можно прочитать тихо и спокойно. А тире указывает, что нужно прочитать с более приподнятой, активной интонацией. Поставили бы вы тире, если бы было не такое красивое слово "восхищался", а какое-то простое? Не было бы тогда смысла в тире. И даже подчёркивать вводное слово не было бы смысла. И ещё, если тире употребляется для подчёркивания чего-либо - оно интонационное.